# Why am I getting "java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" error?

Tags: android, json

I getting

> "Value SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject"

error. I think I have to format the 'SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE', if so please tell me how do I do that ?

```
private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"metadata\":{\"generated\":1462295443000,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10\",\"title\":\"USGS Earthquakes\",\"status\":200,\"api\":\"1.5.2\",\"limit\":10,\"offset\":1,\"count\":10},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.2,\"place\":\"88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\",\"time\":1454124312220,\"updated\":1460674294040,\"tz\":720,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004vvx\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004vvx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":2,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":5.82,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":798,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004vvx\",\"ids\":\",at00o1qxho,pt16030050,us20004vvx,gcmt20160130032510,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.958,\"rms\":1.19,\"gap\":17,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.2 - 88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[158.5463,53.9776,177]},\"id\":\"us20004vvx\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\",\"time\":1453777820750,\"updated\":1460156775040,\"tz\":600,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004uks\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004uks&format=geojson\",\"felt\":null,\"cdi\":null,\"mmi\":4.1,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":572,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004uks\",\"ids\":\",us20004uks,gcmt20160126031023,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.537,\"rms\":0.74,\"gap\":25,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[153.2454,-5.2952,26]},\"id\":\"us20004uks\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.3,\"place\":\"50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\",\"time\":1453695722730,\"updated\":1460156773040,\"tz\":0,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gy9\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gy9&format=geojson\",\"felt\":117,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":5.28,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":695,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gy9\",\"ids\":\",us10004gy9,gcmt20160125042203,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.201,\"rms\":0.92,\"gap\":20,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.3 - 50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-3.6818,35.6493,12]},\"id\":\"us10004gy9\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.1,\"place\":\"86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\",\"time\":1453631430230,\"updated\":1460156770040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gqp\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gqp&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1816,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":6.6,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":1496,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gqp\",\"ids\":\",at00o1gd6r,us10004gqp,ak12496371,gcmt20160124103030,\",\"sources\":\",at,us,ak,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,trump-origin,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.72,\"rms\":2.11,\"gap\":19,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.1 - 86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-153.4051,59.6363,129]},\"id\":\"us10004gqp\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.6,\"place\":\"215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\",\"time\":1453399617650,\"updated\":1459963829040,\"tz\":-420,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004g4l\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004g4l&format=geojson\",\"felt\":11,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":3.92,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":673,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004g4l\",\"ids\":\",at00o1bebo,pt16021050,us10004g4l,gcmt20160121180659,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.413,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":74,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.6 - 215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-106.9337,18.8239,10]},\"id\":\"us10004g4l\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.7,\"place\":\"52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\",\"time\":1452741933640,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebx\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":51,\"cdi\":5.8,\"mmi\":6.45,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":720,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebx\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebx,pt16014050,at00o0xauk,gcmt20160114032534,\",\"sources\":\",us,pt,at,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",associate,cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.281,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.7 - 52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[142.781,41.9723,46]},\"id\":\"us10004ebx\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\",\"time\":1452741928270,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":-240,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebw\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebw&format=geojson\",\"felt\":3,\"cdi\":2.2,\"mmi\":2.21,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":573,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebw\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebw,gcmt20160114032528,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":5.492,\"rms\":1.04,\"gap\":16,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-63.3288,-19.7597,582.56]},\"id\":\"us10004ebw\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.2,\"place\":\"74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\",\"time\":1452532083920,\"updated\":1459304875040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004djn\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004djn&format=geojson\",\"felt\":8,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":3.74,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":594,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004djn\",\"ids\":\",us10004djn,gcmt20160111170803,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.139,\"rms\":0.96,\"gap\":33,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.2 - 74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[141.0867,44.4761,238.81]},\"id\":\"us10004djn\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.5,\"place\":\"227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\",\"time\":1452530285900,\"updated\":1459304874040,\"tz\":480,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004dj5\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004dj5&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":7.5,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":650,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004dj5\",\"ids\":\",at00o0srjp,pt16011050,us10004dj5,gcmt20160111163807,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":3.144,\"rms\":0.72,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.5 - 227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[126.8621,3.8965,13]},\"id\":\"us10004dj5\"},\n" +
        "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6,\"place\":\"Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\",\"time\":1451986454620,\"updated\":1459202978040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004bgk\",\"detail\":\"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004bgk&format=geojson\",\"felt\":0,\"cdi\":1,\"mmi\":0,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":554,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004bgk\",\"ids\":\",us10004bgk,gcmt20160105093415,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":30.75,\"rms\":0.67,\"gap\":71,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"Earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.0 - Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-136.2603,-54.2906,10]},\"id\":\"us10004bgk\"}],\"bbox\":[-153.4051,-54.2906,10,158.5463,59.6363,582.56]}";

private QueryUtils() {

public static ArrayList<Earthquake> extractEarthquakes() {
    ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
        JSONArray earthquakeArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("features");

        for (int i = 0; i < earthquakeArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject currentEarthquake = earthquakeArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("properties");
            String magnitude = properties.getString("mag");
            String location = properties.getString("place");

            String time = properties.getString("time");

            Earthquake earthquake = new Earthquake(magnitude, location, time);
            earthquakes.add(earthquake);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the Earthquake JSON results", e);
    }
    return earthquakes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a JSON object from a string is has to be properly escaped and it currently isn't

There is a lot of JSON in your post so I've taken the first line of the JSON to use as an example (this would be the first features object). I then unescaped the JSON and then validated the json. There are many tools to do this, but I used https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html for formatting and https://jsonlint.com/ for validating the JSON. I found a few issues with the JSON object (around the new line \n escaping). I've been able to then escape the JSON by pasting it into Android Studio as shown below and the JSON now parses the string into a JSONObject.
I suggest you do the same and go line by line until you have validated all of the  JSON and then paste the valid JSON between the quotation marks `private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "";`

Android Studio (and hopefully other IDEs should then escape the JSON correctly, or you'll have to use a JSON escaping utility)

```
private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "{\n" +
            "\t\"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",\n" +
            "\t\"metadata\": {\n" +
            "\t\t\"generated\": 1462295443000,\n" +
            "\t\t\"url\": \"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10\",\n" +
            "\t\t\"title\": \"USGS Earthquakes\",\n" +
            "\t\t\"status\": 200,\n" +
            "\t\t\"api\": \"1.5.2\",\n" +
            "\t\t\"limit\": 10,\n" +
            "\t\t\"offset\": 1,\n" +
            "\t\t\"count\": 10\n" +
            "\t},\n" +
            "\t\"features\": [{\n" +
            "\t\t\"type\": \"Feature\",\n" +
            "\t\t\"properties\": {\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"mag\": 7.2,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"place\": \"88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"time\": 1454124312220,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"updated\": 1460674294040,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"tz\": 720,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"url\": \"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004vvx\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"detail\": \"http://Earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004vvx&format=geojson\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"felt\": 2,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"cdi\": 3.4,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"mmi\": 5.82,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"alert\": \"green\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"status\": \"reviewed\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"tsunami\": 1,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"sig\": 798,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"net\": \"us\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"code\": \"20004vvx\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"ids\": \",at00o1qxho,pt16030050,us20004vvx,gcmt20160130032510,\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"sources\": \",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"types\": \",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"nst\": null,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"dmin\": 0.958,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"rms\": 1.19,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"gap\": 17,\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"magType\": \"mww\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"type\": \"Earthquake\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"title\": \"M 7.2 - 88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\"\n" +
            "\t\t},\n" +
            "\t\t\"geometry\": {\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"type\": \"Point\",\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"coordinates\": [158.5463, 53.9776, 177]\n" +
            "\t\t},\n" +
            "\t\t\"id\": \"us20004vvx\"\n" +
            "\t}]\n" +
            "}";

    JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
```